# Select fields which are not null from dynamically generated column name with 'END as' statement

Tags: mysql, case

Assume I Have an SQL query like this

```
     SELECT player_name,weight,
     CASE WHEN weight > 250 THEN 'over 250'
          WHEN weight > 200 THEN '201-250'
          WHEN weight > 175 THEN '176-200'
        ELSE '' END AS weight_group
   FROM benn.college_football_players
```

I want to display the records which are not null(Weight not null) without disturbing the ELSE ' ',because that would cause so many unnecessary errors in the query,is there a workaround for this?
I have used

```
    where weight_group is not null
```

at the end,but it's throwing an error as 'Invalid Identifier'

Any other work around other than putting this entire select condition in another select statement?

Comment: please make it clear whether you want to exclude those rows where `weight_group` column is empty or where `weight` column is null?

Comment: exclude those where weight column  is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULL` is **not equal** to `''` in `MySQL`. `NULL` means `no data` and `empty string` means `empty string`, they are two different things.

You need to filter data on the basis of empty string like

```
where weight_group != '';
```

Now you can achieve desired result in more than one way.

**1. Using Sub-Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT player_name,weight,
             CASE 
                WHEN weight > 250 THEN 'over 250' 
                WHEN weight > 200 THEN '201-250' 
                WHEN weight > 175 THEN '176-200' 
                ELSE '' 
            END AS weight_group 
      FROM benn.college_football_players) AS t 
WHERE weight_group != '';
```

**2. Using Group By**

```
SELECT player_name,weight,
         CASE WHEN weight > 250 THEN 'over 250'
              WHEN weight > 200 THEN '201-250'
              WHEN weight > 175 THEN '176-200'
              ELSE '' 
          END AS weight_group
FROM benn.college_football_players
GROUP BY weight_group, weight, player_name
HAVING weight_group != '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add just where condition **where weight > 175**

```
SELECT player_name,weight,
 CASE WHEN weight > 250 THEN 'over 250'
      WHEN weight > 200 THEN '201-250'
      WHEN weight > 175 THEN '176-200'
    ELSE '' END AS weight_group FROM benn.college_football_players where weight > 175
```

Here else part not return any thing. Also you can use below code too

```
SELECT player_name,weight,
 CASE WHEN weight > 250 THEN 'over 250'
      WHEN weight > 200 THEN '201-250'
      WHEN weight > 175 THEN '176-200'
END AS weight_group FROM benn.college_football_players where weight > 175
```

Comment: I can't assign any values to where condition,i meant i can't use comparison operators